# Adding fractions in C++ without using functions

Tags: c++

I'm New to C++ and I want to know if there's a way to add two fractions by using the LCM, as i want to display the added fractions in reduced form. I also can't use functions or string or thing of that nature. I attempted to answer it using GCD but this isn't the assignment question so i could some help.
Such as 3/8 + 5/12 = 19/24, i know this it the answer, i just don't know how to get c++ to display it

```
int main()

    int num1,denom1,num2,denom2,num3,denom3,GCD,i;
    while(denom1!=0 || denom2!=0)
    {
    cout<<"Enter Numerator of fraction one ";
    cin>>num1;
    cout<<"Enter Denominator of fraction one ";
    cin>>denom1;
    cout<<"Enter Numerator of fraction two ";
    cin>>num2;
    cout<<"Enter Denominator of fraction two ";
    cin>>denom2;
    num3 = (num1 * denom2) + (denom1 * num2);
    denom3 = denom1 * denom2; 
    cout<<"The answer is "<<num3<<"/"<<denom3;
    }
        if (denom3 == 0)
    {
      exit;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= num3 && i <= denom3; ++i)
    {
      if (num3 % i == 0 && denom3 % i == 0)
        GCD = i;
    }
    cout <<"\n The added fraction is " << num3/GCD << "/" << denom3/GCD;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to base your loop condition on the state of uninitialized variables.

Comment: `exit` is the name of a function. `exit;` doesn't do anything useful. Replace it with `return 0;`.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself.

Comment: *"I also can't use functions"* -- bad news then: you are using a function. It's called `main`. Did you perhaps mean that you cannot use functions **from the standard library**? (Hopefully the restriction is not on helper functions that *you* write, since breaking a task into smaller pieces is good design.)

Comment: What are the values of `denom1` and `denom2`, since they are not initialized, before the `while` statement is reached the first time?

Comment: that seems to work, but I'm not allowed to use class,fractions or any other functions from the standard library. I'm restricted from using helper functions within this assignment The questions has to be solved using the most basic method

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to implement something like

```
 class Fraction{
     private:
     int numerator;
     int denominator;

     public:
     Fraction (int n, int dn);
     void reduce ();
     Fraction add (Fraction a, Fraction b);
     Fraction subtract (Fraction a, Fraction b);
 }
```

Comment: that seems to work, but I'm not allowed to use class,fractions or any other functions from the standard library. I'm restricted from using helper functions within this assignment  The questions has to be solved using the most basic method

Answer (score 0):

I got this code. I bet it can be simplified, but I think you will understand it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int tempNum , tempDenom;
int denom1=8 , denom2=12 , denom3, num1=3 , num2=5, num3;

for(int i = 1 ; ;i++){          // this loop will work untill you find  
                                 multiplier for the first fraction

if ( (denom1 * i) % denom2 == 0){
    
    denom3 = denom1 * i;
    num1 = num1 * i;
    
     break;                     // when you find it, you will end the 
        }                           //loop with break
}

for(int i = 1 ; ;i++){          // this loop will work untill you find  
                                 multiplier for the second fraction

if ( (denom2 * i) % denom1 == 0){
    
    num2 = num2 * i;
    num3 = num1 + num2;
     break;                     // when you find  it, you will end the 
        }                           loop with break
}

for (int i = num3 ; i > 1 ; i--){
    tempNum = num3 % i;   //the % gives you the rest of the divison
    tempDenom = denom3 % i;
    
    if(tempNum == 0 && tempDenom == 0){
        num3 = num3 / i;
        denom3 = denom3 / i;
                break;       // you have simplified the fraction
    }
}
        cout << "The result is : " << num3 << "/" << denom3;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you use the formatting tool `{}` to format this code.  Hard to see any indentation as it is.

Comment: *"i think you will understand it"* -- doubtful. Code-only answers tend to be iffy in the short term and nearly useless in the long term. (Not to mention that your indentation style and excessive blank lines makes the code hard to read.) You should explain what you did in words, in addition to providing the code.